# How to loop through an array containing objects of objects

Tags: javascript

This is my array:

```
[{
    name: "Test",
    skills: {
        agile: true,
        good: true
    }
 },
 {
    name: "Test 2",
    skills: {
        agile: false,
        good: false
    }
 }]
```

I need to find the last element (his index) who has the skill good set to true. The only way I know to fix this is to use a for/if combination. Is there any other faster/optimal way to do it ?

Comment: So, you want to find an element itself (=object) or its index (=number) or both?

Comment: Just the index. I need the index in otder to add similar elements all one next to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is to us a for loop:

```js
var arr = [{
    name: "Test",
    skills: {
        agile: true,
        good: true
    }
 },
 {
    name: "Test 2",
    skills: {
        agile: false,
        good: false
    },
 }]
 
function findLastGoodIndex(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (arr[i].skills.good) {
      return i;
    }
  }
 }

console.log(findLastGoodIndex(arr));
```

Or if the list isn't that large you can combine `reverse` with `findIndex`:

```
arr.reverse().findIndex(x => x.skills.good));
```

Comment: Our answers are similar. Even I though of making a function, but then having `skills.good` as static check killed the idea. Hence went with plain old while

Answer (score 2):

Use filter:

`const goodSkills = myArray.filter(x => x.skills.good)`

Then get the last item:

`goodSkills[goodSkills.length - 1]`

Or if you only need the index, and we treat `name` as a unique key:

`const lastGoodIndex = myArray.findIndex(x => x.name === goodSkills[goodSkills.length - 1].name)`

You can then use `lastGoodIndex` for whatever nefarious purpose you have in mind.

Alternatively if `name` is not a unique key, I suggest just using `forEach`:

```
let lastGoodIndex;
myArray.forEach((x, i) => lastGoodIndex = x.skills.good ? i : lastGoodIndex);
console.log(lastGoodIndex);
```

Comment: If there's no unique key I would suggest just using `myArray.forEach((x, i) => lastGoodIndex = x.skills.good ? i : lastGoodIndex)` and ditch filter completely (as nice as it is).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 3 rows:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    name: "Test",
    skills: {
      agile: true,
      good: true
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Test 2",
    skills: {
      agile: false,
      good: false
    },
  }
]
 
var lastIndex;
arr.forEach(function(item, i) {
  if(item.skills.good) lastIndex = i;
})

console.log(lastIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `index` of last element that has `good = true` your best option is to use `for/if` (perhaps going backwards, i.e. `i--` if you can guess where can you expect the `good` item?).

`filter` will find the item(s) too, and it also has `index` property, but generally it's slower than for/if.

`forEach` will also generally be slower than `for/if`.

edit:styling.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to search the last value, you should search in descending order. This would prevent any unnecessary iterations.

```js
var data = [{
    name: "Test",
    skills: {
      agile: true,
      good: true
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Test 2",
    skills: {
      agile: false,
      good: false
    }
  }
];

var i = data.length;
var result = null;
while (i--) {
  if (data[i].skills.good) {
    result = i;
    break;
  }
}


console.log(result);
```